# nginx not sending health check message to reverse proxy configured

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Well i am using nginx-1.7.2 on Linux sle11,

I have a reverse proxy configured, and calls are routing fine, 
Now when i configured a health check using "nginx_upstream_check" module, there are no health check messages sent to servers, here is my config file.

```
    upstream ote_server_list
 {
    server 10.18.149.5:1111;
    server 10.18.149.5:2222;
    check interval=5000 rise=2 fall=3 timeout=3000 type=http;
    check_http_send "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
}

    server
         {
        listen       8488;
        server_name  localhost;

        access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
        location /
        {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass      http://ote_server_list/ote/transcode/;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
```

I also checked tcpdump at the server, it does not received any message from the nginx IP. is anything wrong with my config?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason, It was my mistake that i forgot to apply patch before i compile "nginx_upstream_check" module, patch file is already present in the **nginx_upstream_check_module-master.zip** downloaded from github.

**Solution:**

```
cd /root/nginx/nginx-1.7.2;
patch -p1 < /root/nginx/nginx-1.7.2/src/nginx_upstream_check_module-master/check_1.7.2+.patch;
```

Once patch is applied, perform `configure` `make` and use newly compiled **nginx** binary.

Now i can see the HealthCheck message sent from nginx to the upstream servers.

[image]